# PostgreSQL index for like 'abc%' searching

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-orm-postgres

I have postgreSQL table with city list (>1M) and I need to search over this table by pattern like 'abc%'.
I created B-tree index on `city.name` column, and here is what i got:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM city WHERE NAME ~~* 'Мос%' 
Seq Scan on city  (cost=0.00..44562.62 rows=117 width=131)
```

And the exact select:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM city WHERE NAME = 'Москва' 
Index Scan using city_name_idx on city  (cost=0.43..12.33 rows=2 width=131)
```

Is there any way to use standart index to achieve good performance on first select?

I am using Symfony2/Doctrine2, so it's not very easy (and I do not want) to implement db-specific things here.

Comment: It looks like ~~* maps to ILIKE which may not be supported by the B-tree index; try it with LIKE instead. You may also have trouble if your db locale is not 'C'. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html for more details. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126615/postgresql-ilike-versus-tsearch for a related discussion.

Comment: citext (case insensitive text) column type can be also helpful for ilike searches. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/citext.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- To speed up `LIKE` (case sensitive), create an index like this:

  ```
  create index indexname on city (name text_pattern_ops);
  ```
- To speed up `ILIKE` or `~~*` , in addition to `LIKE`, assuming PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer, create an index like this:

  ```
  create index indexname on city  using gin(name gin_trgm_ops);
  ```

  `gin_trgm_ops` is provided by the [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension that should be added if not already present in the database.

Comment: I used `text_pattern_ops` and get `Index Scan using city_name_idx on city  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=117 width=131)`. I can not use `ILIKE` or `LOWER`, but I can deal with it. Thanks