# Speeding up a complex query (indexing or other techniques)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to speed up a complex rails query that basically searches for a location on a venue. The location can be ether a name, city, county or country.

I tried adding an index, however I don't think i have done this correctly.

This is my schema for venues:

```
  create_table "venues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "postplace"
    t.string   "map_address"
    t.decimal  "latitude"
    t.decimal  "longitude"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "website"
    t.integer  "import_id"
    t.string   "postal_address"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "county"
    t.string   "region"
    t.string   "country_name"
  end

  add_index "venues", ["country_name"], name: "index_venues_on_country_name", using: :btree
  add_index "venues", ["import_id"], name: "index_venues_on_import_id", using: :btree
  add_index "venues", ["name", "city", "county", "country"], name: "location", using: :btree
  add_index "venues", ["slug"], name: "index_venues_on_slug", unique: true, using: :btree
```

And this is the relevant part of my query:

```
  def filter_on_location
    @events = events.
      joins(:venue).where(
        "venues.city ILIKE :location
        OR venues.county ILIKE :location
        OR venues.country ILIKE :location
        OR venues.name = :location",
        location: params[:location])
  end
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: although it might be obvious to most, please add the database server you're using as tag

Comment: Added postgres tag. `ILIKE` is postgres specific AFAIK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126615/postgresql-ilike-versus-tsearch

Comment: There is no good way for this query to avoid a table scan while you're using B-tree indexes. Search for details on Postgres full-text search and you have a chance.